# localStorage integer defined elsewhere becomes undefined when called on new page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have 3 values that i define in localStorage in a javascript file. 2 are strings and 1 is an integer. Because i cannot pass parameters through the onLoad, I redirect to a new html page, assign each stored value to a variable and then call the function onload that uses the values. The strings work but the integer is always returned undefined. I thought that it was returned as a string and the function attempts to use it as an integer. So i tried parseInt() and JSON.parse() but it is still returned undefined. The integer is defined and used to load a page but it cannot be retrieved in a page.

HTML

```
<script>
var winLOCAL = localStorage.getItem('WinLost');//defined in GotoWinScreen(win) which is called in the 'Play' Challenge functions
var itmLOCAL = localStorage.getItem('itemchoice');//defined in StartChallenge()
var challLOCAL = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('challNum'));//defined in selectChall().
</script>
<script src="game.js"></script>
<link href="game.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onLoad="WinLose()">
<div class="choice" id="placeHere">
<h1 id="winMessage"></h1>
<button onClick="Forest()">Continue</button>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function WinLose() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("placeHere");
    var myH1 = document.getElementById("winMessage");
    var content = document.createTextNode("");
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lives")) == 0) {
        content = document.createTextNode("<h3>You have run out of lives</h3><br /><h1>GAME OVER</h1>");
        myDiv.appendChild(content);
    } else if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("challengeNumber")) == 3) {
        GotoChallenge(5);
    } else {
        switch (challLOCAL) {
            case 0:
                if (itmLOCAL == "shovel") {
                    if (winLOCAL == true) {
                        content = document.createTextNode("You dig around your legs until you are able to free them");
                    } else {
                        content = document.createTextNode("You attempt to dig around your legs but the compressed sand is like concrate and will not release you.");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: please see your code which u have pasted here it gives so many errors?

Comment: @kki3908050 - please write with both english words _and_ grammar. Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Please write with both English words and grammar. Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: This is correct English,thanks for sharing.and please make sense so that i can understand her question eaisly.

Comment: The code that I have posted only has the one error that i specified. localStorage.getItem('challNum'), which should be an integer, becomes undefined when the new page loads even though the two strings are not. The actual localStorage variable is undefined not the variable i assign it to on the html page.

Comment: I just adding parseInt() to every reference of localStorage.getItem('challNum'). It now returns NaN. So now it expects a number?

Answer (score -1):

### **i tried something hope this will help

### your index file:-**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="other.js"></script>
<script>
var winLOCAL = localStorage.getItem('WinLost');//defined in GotoWinScreen(win) which is called in the 'Play' Challenge functions
var itmLOCAL = localStorage.getItem('itemchoice');//defined in StartChallenge()
var challLOCAL = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('challNum'));//defined in selectChall().
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="choice" id="placeHere">
<h1 id="winMessage"></h1>
<button onClick="Forest()">Continue</button>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
</body>
</html></html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var winLOCAL = localStorage.getItem('WinLost');//defined in GotoWinScreen(win) which is called in the 'Play' Challenge functions
    var itmLOCAL = localStorage.getItem('itemchoice');//defined in StartChallenge()
    var challLOCAL = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('challNum'));
    alert(winLOCAL);
     alert(itmLOCAL);
     alert(challLOCAL);
function WinLose() {
    alert('loaded');
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("placeHere");
    var myH1 = document.getElementById("winMessage");
    var content = document.createTextNode("");
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lives")) == 0) {
        content = document.createTextNode("<h3>You have run out of lives</h3><br /><h1>GAME OVER</h1>");
        myDiv.appendChild(content);
    } else if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("challengeNumber")) == 3) 
    {
        GotoChallenge(5);
    } else {
        switch (challLOCAL) {
            case 0:
                if (itmLOCAL == "shovel") {
                     if (winLOCAL == true) {
                        content = document.createTextNode("You dig around your legs until you are able to free them");
                         } 
                     else {
                        content = document.createTextNode("You attempt to dig around your legs but the compressed sand is like concrate and will not release you.");
                         }
                }
        }
    }
}
WinLose();
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("age");
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sex");

        });
```

### **your js file say other.js**

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "malia");
localStorage.setItem("age", "22");
localStorage.setItem("sex", "female");
localStorage.setItem("WinLost", "win or lost");
localStorage.setItem("itemchoice", "selection");
localStorage.setItem("challNum", "10");
```